# How can insert a lot of items with ContentResolver fast

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to add words to user dictionary in bulks (tens of thousands of words).

I've tried to

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                int counter = 0;
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String word = scanner.nextLine();
                    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getBaseContext(), word, 255, null, Locale.getDefault());
                    setProgress((float) counter++ * 100 / linesCount);
                }
```

and I've also tried bulkinsert

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
            int counter = 0;
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                words.add(scanner.nextLine());
                if (words.size() >= capacity) {
                    MyUserDictionary.addWords(getBaseContext(), words, Locale.getDefault());
                    words.clear();
                    setProgress((float) counter * 100 / linesCount);
                }
                counter++;
            }
            if (!words.isEmpty()) {
                MyUserDictionary.addWords(getBaseContext(), words, Locale.getDefault());
            }
```

And I've tried applyBatch.

All this method results with very long running time.

I know that sqlite can do better with transactions.

Do you know more faster way to do it?

EDIT1:

```
  final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

        final int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;

        List<ContentValues> valueses = new ArrayList<ContentValues>(words.size());
        for (String word: words) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(COLUMN_COUNT);
            values.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, word);
            values.put(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY);
            values.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, null == locale ? null : locale.toString());
            values.put(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID, 0); // TODO: Get App UID
            values.put(UserDictionary.Words.SHORTCUT, "");
            valueses.add(values);
        }
        resolver.bulkInsert(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, valueses.toArray(new ContentValues[valueses.size()]));
```

Comment: Post your code with bulkInsert()

Comment: I think that I need somehow retrieve database and then do all things myself in raw sql with transactions, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: so you didnot try a bulkInsert ? do it so...

Comment: What?
how is resolver.bulkInsert is not a bulkInsert?

Comment: again, did you call ContentResolver.bulkInsert(Uri url, ContentValues[] values) ?

Comment: again, Do you see my updated code, where I'm doing exactly that? =)

Comment: did you override bulkInsert in your provider?

Comment: I haven't created my provider. If I would create my provider, I would need to get database. How can I do that if that is not my database?

Comment: well, you cannot access that db, thats why ContentProviders are for

Comment: So there is no way to insert faster?

Comment: i see two solutions: to change UserDictionary.Words content provider and override its bulkInsert, or change its db to be world writable...

Comment: Can you expand your answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48992/discussion-between-user1685095-and-pskink)